# Date Picker Validation in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, android-dialog, android-datepicker

when today date is between 1-15 than previous month 16-31 date enabled.
when today date is between 16-31 than current month 1-15 date enabled. My Code is please resolve my problem:

```
 private void DateDialog() {
        final DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,android.app.AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int day, int month, int year) {
                cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                //int curyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                cal.set(day, month, year);

            }
        }, day, month, year);
        if ((day < 15)) {
            int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            Log.e("Month", String.valueOf(month));
            int days = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            Log.e("days", String.valueOf(days));
            int lastday = days-day;
            Log.e("Lastday", String.valueOf(lastday));
            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate((month-1)+System.currentTimeMillis()-(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24*(days-day)));
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
//        dp_time.setMinDate(now);
            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate((month-1)+now +(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *15));


        }
        else if ((day > 15)) {
            int days = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            Log.e("days", String.valueOf(days));
            int lastday = days - 15;
            Log.e("lastday", String.valueOf(lastday));
            int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            Log.e("Month", String.valueOf(month));
            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate((1000*60*60*24*(day+1)));
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
//        dp_time.setMinDate(now);
            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(now +(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *lastday));
        }
        dpDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `DatePickerDialog` constructor values are not correct, you passed day instead of year and vice-versa, also there are few problems in conditions.
here's updated code. Just replace your code with this one.

```
  private void DateDialog() {
         final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        final DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, android.app.AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int day, int month, int year) {
                cal.set(day, month, year);



                //  cal.set(day, month, year);


            }
        }, year, month, day);

        if (day > 15) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

        } else {
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);

            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

        }

        dpDialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: Hello code is fine but in every time the date of 16-31 calendar change after 1 time selection each every time i want fix it. and in current calender it select 1 to current date active but i want also 1-15 date active

Comment: can you please share your complete code, how you are making selection of dates and also the way you are getting day,year and month from calendar, so that i can review your code where you are making mistake.

Comment: Hello code is fine but each time of previous month calendar change after date selection but i want always show 16 to last day of month of previous month .

Comment: please give solution please\

Comment: The problem is every time you select date if moves to your selected date,  to avoid this what you can do. You need to take two calendars,
every time you call DateDialog() method re-initialize your calender.

Comment: i edited my answer please try this and let me know if stil something wrong

Comment: Hello i don,t understand what are you saying please give proper solution.